# Embedding of some function spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Consider the strictly monotone continuous function $d:\mathbb{R^+}\to\mathbb{R^+}$, and denote by $\mathcal{D}$ the space of all measurable functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$\int_0^1 d(|f(x)|) dx<\infty$$

I am wondering if there is any result on the (dense and continuous) embedding of this function space in the $L_p$ spaces?

Comment: Your cadidate to embedding is 
$
\mathcal{D}\ni f\longmapsto 
\Big(  x\mapsto d(f(x))  \Big)\in L_p(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),\lambda)
$
?

Comment: The norm in $\mathcal{D}$ is $\| f\|_{\infty}=\inf\{ C \in \mathbb{R}: \lambda(\{ x : f(x)> C\})=0\}$ ?

Comment: I'd say the point is we need to replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{R}^+$ in order to use $d^{-1}$ to make sense to $f \oplus g$ and linearity  @MathOverview

Comment: I added strict monotinicity of the function $d$, that ensures the existence of the inverse.

Comment: @Sara: Your "space" is not closed under addition and scalar multiplication in general. So why are you interested in these spaces and what exactly do you mean by an embedding? Just $\mathcal{D}\subset L^p$?

Comment: If we assumed that the function $d$ is a convex funcion, then we can have a Minkowski-like inequality, and thus; have the space closed under addition. why is it not closed under scalar multiplication? Yes, just $\mathcal{D}\subset L^p$ densely and continuously.

Comment: You can look for information about [Orlicz spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space).